# How to create a file object in python without using open()

Tags: file, python-2.7, python-3.x

Use case:
I have a method doSomething(file) which accepts the file object and does something, I can't alter this method.

Now, to have the file to pass to doSomething, i need to open it through open() method but i don't have that file to store on localhost and i am allowed to but i have the file contents and file name stored in python variables. Is there a way to get file object from these two variables ?

Answer (score 2):

The `StringIO` class is a file-like class, which stores the contents in memory. You can create an instance with your content, and pass it to `doSomething(strio)`.

From the [docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)

```
import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write('First line.\n')
print >>output, 'Second line.'
```

Comment: Note that you will need to use `output.seek(0)` after writing or the function that gets the file-like object will have the offset after the last write rather than at the start of the file-like object.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is 8-bit string or Unicode, StringIO is a good option. However if your data is binary or mix of 8-bit string and Unicode, then StringIO will fail. BytesIO is the recommended option in this case.

```
import io

your_data = b'\x02\x1b\x92\x1fs\x96\x97\xe8\x01'
sd = io.BytesIO()
sd.write(your_data)
sd.seek(0) # Seek to the beginning

# sd can act like a file handle. Pass it to your function.
```